# Python array like feature

Tags: python

Hello guys i have seen some code in python which is really confusing me ..

The code which i have seen is like below

```
row = rs.fetchone()
print 'Id:', row[0]
print 'Name:', row['name']
print 'Age:', row.age
print 'Password:', row[users.c.password]
```

I know row['name'] means row.name .so will this print the result of row['name'] with the message name ? or it fetches from row and display it as name ?..

Am little bit confused with this.So any help to me would be great thanks and the answer will be appreciated ...Thanks in advance ..

As by larsks answer i have coded like this

```
class student (object):

 age = 30
c = student()
 row.age

print 'age:', row[student.c.age]
```

But i have got an error like this ..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>

    class student (object):



 File "<pyshell#5>", line 3, in student

    c = student()

NameError: name 'student' is not defined
```

I didnt get output 30 as i expected ..:(

Comment: "row['name'] means row.name" - no it doesn't.

Comment: then ? can you please explain what role does it play ?

Comment: i think in javascript its like that ...not more knwoledge about python ...can you please explain me with an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

> print 'Id:', row[0]

This prints the first element of a list.  For example:

```
>>> row = [ 'a', 'b', 'c']
>>> row[0]
'a'
```

---

> print 'Name:', row['name']

This looks up the key `name` in a dictionary.  For example:

```
>>> row = { 'name': 'lars', 'species': 'cat' }
>>> row['name']
'lars'
```

---

> print 'Age:', row.age

This looks up *attribute* on an object.  For example:

```
>>> class Row (object):
...     age = 30
... 
>>> row = Row()
>>> row.age
30
```

---

> print 'Password:', row[users.c.password]

This is just a combination of the above.  It looks up the `password` attribute of the `c` attribute of `users`, and then uses that value as a key to find the corresponding value in a dictionary.

Comment: i didnt understood about c here ?...where is it declaired ?

Comment: In your example, it would be an attribute of `users`, whatever that is.

Comment: ..I didnt get ..please can you update your code ..attribute means like .class users(object),age =30; c = new users() ..So you mean the attribute like this ?..is this you mean by c as mentioned in ur answer ?

Comment: I would start with a good Python tutorial.  [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/) is a good one and quite thorough, although there are others. The official documentation includes [a tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/), as well.  The [modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) and [classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) sections talk about the `.` operator in varying degrees of detail.

Comment: If the same variable is used for all instances of `row` here, then `[0]` would not reference "the first" element because `['name']` implies that it is a `dict`-like object of some sort.  So `0` and `'name'` are both treated as just keys.

Comment: @larsks the asker's code sample has the reuse of `row` this way, so I base my assumptions on that.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that I assumed it was just a collection of random things, but if this all comes from an actual chunk of code somewhere then SimonT is correct.

Comment: i didnt get what you are saying ..??...i just need to know from where the varibale c comes ..is that the object of class ?

Comment: @larsks i dodnt need a tutorial website .i just need to know where the varibale c comes ?...

Comment: i know what you have meant ..by i didnt get the answer ..i have created a varibale c as the object of class ..i have updated the code ..please help ..